# Check if TableLayoutPanel contains instance?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, instance

I would like to check if a TableLayoutPanels already contains an instance of a UserControl but it don't works like this. mainActiveContr != userControl are both an instance of the AddEntryControl so shouldn't it be false? It's true ...
Contains also seems to return true, but shouldn't it return false??

```
private UserControl mainActiveContr;

private void IsUserControlAlreadyActive(UserControl userControl)
{
    if (!tableLayoutPanel1.Contains(userControl) && mainActiveContr != userControl)
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(userControl, 3, 2);

}
```

If someone clicks on of the buttons i create an instance of the UserControl and then i would like to check it.

```
AddEntryControl formChild1 = new AddEntryControl();
IsUserControlAlreadyActive(formChild1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the *types* of the user controls, because each *instance* is unique:

```
using System.Linq;
...

if (!tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<UserControl>()
                      .Select(u => u.GetType())
                      .Any(t => t.Equals(userControl.GetType())))
```

And a similar check for `mainActiveContr`.

Comment: You're right, didn't even noticed that a namespace was missing, sorry. ;) Thanks for your help.!